# Using Observable.interval() to advance time for "time blocks" stored in an array

Tags: android, rx-java

New to RxJava - looking for some feedback.

Scenario: I have a list of time blocks of various lengths (i.e one is 5 minutes long, another 30 seconds, etc). I use Observable.from to create an observable: `timeline = Observable.from(timeBlocks);` What I'd like to do is mix this with an interval observer, `Observable<Long> intervalObs = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` to progress through time for each time block in sequence. So if the first time block's duration is 5 minutes and 5 minutes have passed then move on to the next time block in sequence.

Some other details:

- the list can change (I'm not even sure the best way to deal with that using rx) so block can be added/removed/have their duration changes/re-ordered.
- timer needs to be able to pause/stop
- Other components will also need to tap into this stream (to update UI for example)

Right now this is what I have after trying several approaches that seems to work but also seems inefficient and just looks wrong (I subscribe when time starts and unsubscribe when pausing/stopping):

```
intervalObs 
 .subscribe(new Subscriber() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    timeline.first(new Func1<TimeBlock, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(TimeBlock timeBlock) {
                            return timeBlock.getTimeLeft() > 0;
                        }
                    }).subscribe(new Action1<TimeBlock>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(TimeBlock timeBlock) {
                            timeBlock.addTime(1000);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

What's a better way to do this? Should I structure things differently/conceptualize it in a different way?

Let me try to clear up the use case:

An app that lets you create lists of tasks and assign a duration to them. You can then import any subset of those tasks into a timer. The timer just increments the time spent on each task starting with the top one first. When the task's duration is reached, you move on to the next task. You should be able to pause/resume/re-arrange the order of the tasks/edit the tasks/etc and the timer adjusts.

You can also pre-select a cycle pattern - i.e say you want to work in blocks of 25 minutes. The timer will create however many time blocks of 25 minutes needed to complete all the tasks based on their total duration. The timer then does the same thing as described above, increasing the time spent on each time block (and the time spent on the tasks contained with in it) until duration is reached then moves on to the next.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the desired use case, but perhaps this example code can provide some guidance:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import rx.Observable;

public class TimelineDelay {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Observable<Long> timelineInMilliseconds = Observable.just(
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));

        timelineInMilliseconds
                .flatMap(millis -> Observable.timer(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(x -> millis))
                .map(millis -> "Event after waiting " + millis + " milliseconds")
                .toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
Event after waiting 2000 milliseconds
Event after waiting 5000 milliseconds
Event after waiting 10000 milliseconds
```

- The timeline is dynamic and whatever you want it to be. As it emits it will react.
- This will wait for each time block and then emit.
- Subscribing (generally using map/flatMap/etc) allows you to do something on a UI based on the time intervals.

Note however that it does not retain order as it uses `flatMap` so will allow multiple time blocks to run concurrently. If you instead want them to execute sequentially, then use `concatMap` so it will only allow one time block at a time to be waited upon.

That changes like this and retains order:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import rx.Observable;

public class TimelineDelay {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Observable<Long> timelineInMilliseconds = Observable.just(
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));

        timelineInMilliseconds
                .concatMap(millis -> Observable.timer(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(x -> millis))
                .map(millis -> "Event after waiting " + millis + " milliseconds")
                .toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

So it now outputs like this:

```
Event after waiting 5000 milliseconds
Event after waiting 2000 milliseconds
Event after waiting 10000 milliseconds
```

Comment: Going to experiment with this approach and in the meantime I've updated the question to try to clarify the use case.